# Ruby AJAX request delete table row

Tags: ruby, ajax

I have a project (unfortunately i can't show that all) and my task is to delete table row when clicking a link using AJAX request.

My page file has structure like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<a href="account/1" "data-id": "1", "data-method": "delete">
</tr>
<tr>
<a href="account/2" "data-id": "2", "data-method": "delete">
</tr>
</table>
```

By default it's deleted using Ruby method delete. 
When we have only one row, it should be deleted using Ruby logic, if more - by AJAX request.

In my removeButtonController I defined a, href, closest tr, account id and i don't know how to put it right to AJAX request.
sorry that i can't give you more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to